# Как в БД организовать хранения количественной информации о сущностях?

Tags: база-данных

Есть условный пост и условный пользователь. Мною же написанное ТЗ диктует, что пост должен отражать общее количество просмотров поста пользователями. От одного пользователя может быть только один просмотр, дабы не было накрутки.

Какими плюсами и минусами по простоте поддержки и производительности обладают следующие два варианта:

1. Просмотр пользователя заносится записью в отдельной таблице, а при отображении поста его количество просмотров подсчитывается путем считывания значений всех записей таблицы, связанных с этим постом

| Views | Posts |
| --- | --- |
| — id | — id |
| — user_id | — body |
| — post_id |  |

2. Каждый просмотр пользователя просто учитывается напрямую в теле поста. То есть, отдельная таблица под просмотры не создается.

| Posts |
| --- |
| — id |
| — body |
| — views_count |

Я не обладаю ни навыками проектирования баз данных, ни знаниями о внутреннем устройстве механизмов SQL-баз данных, поэтому вопрос производительности для меня стоит остро ввиду незнания.

Просто представить ситуацию: проект набрал 20 000 постов за год, каждый пост просмотрели 1 000 пользователей. Это 20 000 х 1 000 = 20 000 000 записей в таблице Views. И при отображении поста в ленте надо каждый раз проходиться по этим двадцати миллионам записей, чтобы просто вывести красивую циферку на радость глаз пользователя.

Проект прожил пять лет и накопил 100 000 постов, каждый пост просмотрели 5000 пользователей. 100 000 х 5 000 = 500 000 000. Цифра еще более устрашающая.

Comment: Одно другому не мешает, можно использовать оба варианта одновременно. И если вы не будете создавать таблицу просмотров, то не очень понятно, как вы собираетесь проверять наличие «только одного просмотра»

Comment: @andreymal у меня тоже появлялись такие мысли, и все они вытекли в "Создать еще одну таблицу для сверки пользователей", что как бы противоречит идее о снижении количества записей. 

То бишь, в моем понимании первый вариант позволяет отслеживать действия пользователей ценой большой нагрузки на физическую память и процессорное время, а второй вариант обладает дырой, позволяющей в два счета накручивать просмотры.

Как одновременно удовлетворить вопросы производительности и отслеживания действий пользователя — хз

Comment: Никто не заставляет грузить в память всю таблицу целиком, и грамотно поставленные индексы позволят избежать просмотра миллионов ненужных записей, поэтому первый вариант не такой уж и страшный

Comment: В таблице Views можно убрать колонку Id. Ключом будет пара user_id, post_id. / В современном алчном мире таблица наподобие Views крайне необходима. Самое ценное сейчас - это информация! Данные о пользователях, об их предпочтениях и т. п. Наличие такой таблицы позволит отслеживать интересы юзеров и впаривать им релевантную рекламу. Се ля ви.